# "The function `hello`" or "The `hello` function"

Tags: word-order

When writing technical articles, I often have issues with the word order in the following situations:

- The color red.
- The `.jpg` extension.
- The variable `foo`.
- The "Further Notes" section.
- The movie "Titanic".
- The `hello` function.

When I try to change the order, sometimes I find it weird, sometimes not... How is this construction called? Is there a consistent rule? When to use one over the other? Thanks.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/296134/138287, though my answer there is not very good...

Comment: @AndyBonner Press the button "I understand the risks". Press the "I understand the risks" button.

Comment: @AndyBonner To me, the second feels weird. By default, I try to stick with "the name goes after the thing", like "The movie 'Titanic'", but I intentionally gave some examples where the opposite feels natural to me in my original post.

Comment: @AndyBonner I think the rule is: if it's the name/title that identifies the thing (like my brother Jake), and not an adjective that qualifies the thing, it goes after. This post https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39737/ about "the red color" vs "the color red" is interesting. The first one is pointing to a color that is in the family of reds (the red-ish color among others), the second is pointing to the color identified as / named "red". To keep the first order, I would add: "I like red _as a_ color", or "I like the color _named_ red".

Comment: More flavors of the same question so we are all on the same boat (you can see these linked questions in the right sidebar): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162569/
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154529/
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187038/
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59385/
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138587/

Comment: @nelly_the_jelly re: buttons — in that instance I'd normally opt with the first, if the button text is short — Press the "OK" button. Press the "Cancel" button. If it's something long I'd probably add in a 'helper' word, e.g: "Press the button labelled 'I understand the risks'". "Enter your purchase order number in the text titled 'Other notes related to your query'". Not that without the words "labelled" or "titled" it's incorrect, I just find it flows better as a sentence

Comment: @anotherdave I agree with short and descriptive names placed before the category. "Press the 'Cancel' button" is at the same time:
- Press the cancel button.
- Press the button named "Cancel" or Press "Cancel" as a button.
For more complicated names, I also agree that putting some filler words can make the sentence clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've hit the nail on the head in the comments. (By the way, let's note that this discussion is entirely about the order of pairs of nouns. If one of the words is an adjective, there's no question the adjective comes first in English. In "the color red," "red" is a noun, but in "the red color," it's an adjective, just like "the red car.")

To help clarify, these constructions have a "category" and an "instance" of a thing in that category. So in "the movie *Titanic*," the category is "movie" and the instance is "*Titanic*." Similarly, "variable" is the category and "foo" is the instance.

I think you've hit on the answer: what makes the difference is the degree to which the "instance" can work as an identifier on its own—a name, a title, a proper *or* "proper-ish" noun. Could you leave the "category" word out of your sentence and still be understood? If so, the category should probably come first. "Let's watch the movie *Titanic*" could equate to "Let's watch *Titanic*," with little need even to establish the context of movies. As the answer about *[Die Hard](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59385/the-movie-die-hard-or-the-die-hard-movie)* shows, when the instance really is a true proper noun (a unique title, etc.), putting the category second changes the meaning (making the instance work like an adjective).

Many of your examples could go either way, but the order could give a slight alteration in emphasis. For "file extension" and ".jpg," I might put the category first if the emphasis was on jpg: "Filter for the file extensions '.jpg' and '.png.'" But the reverse if the emphasis is on "file extension": "Don't confuse the 'jpg' folder with the 'jpg' file extension." Similarly, say I have a script named "setup." If I say, out loud, "Run the setup script," I could be using "setup" as an adjective and the script might actually be named "init_setup." But if I say "Run the script 'setup,'" I'm clearly using its name.

Comment: I like your answer, thanks! "Run the `setup` script" feels natural because the name is well chosen so it also describes the role of the script. A more complicated (or undescriptive) name would go after: "Run the setup script `~/bin/1337_setup.sh`" like "The variable X". There are still some contexts in which it feels slightly odd to me, but the more I see it, the more natural it becomes. :)

Comment: This discussion reminds me of *nominal* vs *structural* typing in programming languages: in ’The movie *Star Wars* is great’, *Star Wars* is a name of the movie (nominal), whereas in ’The *Star Wars* movie is great’, *Star Wars* is a property of the movie (structural).

Answer (score 1):

Nouns go

- *before* when they act as *modifiers* (e.g. ’the **ice** cream’, ’the **olive** oil’, ’the **baby** mama’, ’the **office** manager’), so they cannot be removed;
- *after* when they act as *identifiers* (e.g. ’the singer **Elvis Presley**’, ‘the variable ***x***’, ’the button **Sign up for the digest**’, ’the path **/usr/bin/env**’), so the nouns before can be removed.

Some nouns can act as both (e.g. ’the ***Star Wars*** movie’ and ’the movie ***Star Wars***’, ’the **Karen** customer’ and ’the customer **Karen**’, ’the **About** section’ and ’the section **About**’, ’the **HOME** environment variable’ and ’the environment variable **HOME**’, ‘the **print** function’ and ‘the function **print**’, ’the **package.json** file’ and ’the file **package.json**’, ’the **--help** command-line option’ and ’the command-line option **--help**’, ‘the **GET** method’ and ‘the method **GET**’, ‘the **200 (OK)** status code’ and ‘the status code **200 (OK)**’, ’the **Host** header field’ and ’the header field **Host**’).